# Unsubscribe reason retrieval

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I am retrieving Subscriber attributes and data from the "All Subscribers" list. I am getting all data except 1: Unsubscribed Reason.

Message: Error: The Request Property(s) UnsubscribeReason do not match with the fields of Subscriber retrieve

I tried UnsubscribeReason, UnsubscribedReason, Unsubscribe Reason and no luck

then I decided to use "theLogUnsubEvent Execute Call" to get the Unsubscribe 'Reason' from the return object, but even though I can see the user has unsubscribed and has a reason attribute in "all subscribers" list, this "theLogUnsubEvent Execute Call" will return OK with no data.

Can you help me retrieve the reason to unsubscribe please?
theLogUnsubEvent documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html#why-use-the-logunsubevent-execute-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [SubscriberStatusEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/retrieving_the_subscriberstatusevent.html?q=reason) SOAP object, which includes the unsubscribe reason.  You can update the filter to suit your requirements.  This particular object doesn't appear in the documentation, except for this example.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <Options>
               <Client>
                  <ID>12345</ID>
               </Client>
            </Options>
            <ObjectType>SubscriberStatusEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberID</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>CurrentStatus</Properties>
            <Properties>PreviousStatus</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>ReasonUnsub</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                  <Property>CurrentStatus</Property>
                  <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                  <Value>Unsubscribed</Value>
               </LeftOperand>
               <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
               <RightOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                  <Property>CreatedDate</Property>
                  <SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
                  <DateValue>2011-04-07T19:58:33.434707Z</DateValue>
               </RightOperand>
            </Filter>
            <RetrieveAllSinceLastBatch>true</RetrieveAllSinceLastBatch>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here are the verified retrieveable properties:

```
Client.ID
CreatedDate
CurrentStatus
ObjectID
PreviousStatus
ReasonUnsub
SubscriberID
SubscriberKey
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Is there a FuelSDK method to retrieve this data? I've checked it and could not see. Since I've been working with FuelSDK, ideally I want to keep all my api connection to the sdk

Comment: I doubt it. I stay away from the SDKs.